# Question about K-Fold cross validation on how to split the data set

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a data set with 500 users and am trying to do keystroke authentication analysis. Each user has one true comment about a restaurant and one fake comment about a restaurant(pretend to have been to the restaurant), together with their keycode and timestamps(time for keyup and keydown). 
I would like to do a 5-fold cross validation of my data. Is it a good idea to do it by splitting the users into 5 groups with equal number or by splitting each comment into 5 parts with equal length?

Thanks a lot for anyone who could give me some suggestions on this problem!

Comment: Given that your dataset is not very big I would recommend using bootstrap instead of $k$-fold cross-validation.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely consider bootstrapping. As if I use 5-fold cross validation, which approach above would you suggest?

Comment: What you describe is simple vs. stratified sampling. I would draw more attention to the fact that you want the proportion of `FAKE`/`REAL` reviews to be similar to the proportion expected in a real world setting. For training your classifier I do not think it will make a huge difference especially as you have artificially created a 50-50 split already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I'm trying to distinguish between true reviews and fake reviews by analyzing keystroke pattern, either for all users or for an individual user. Since the data set only provides one true review and one fake review per user, I couldn't change the ratio.